# Select last of type regardless of parent relationship

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to select the `:last-of-type` of the following `articles` within a grand parent regardless of the parent. i.e. I want the last article within the grand parents.

The issue I have is the `:last-of-type` selects the last within its direct parent and the parent divs will always be in the DOM.

As a last resort I can do some hacky js to add a class to the last article but I would like to solve this only using css if I can.

```css
.grandParent article:last-of-type {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="grandParent">
  <div class="parent">
    <article>not this one</article>
    <article>not this one</article>
    <article>not this one</article>
    <article>not this one</article>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <article>I WANT THIS ONE</article>
  </div>
</div>

<br />

<div class="grandParent">
  <div class="parent">
    <article>not this one</article>
    <article>not this one</article>
    <article>not this one</article>
    <article>I WANT THIS ONE</article>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
  </div>
</div>

<br />

<div class="grandParent">
  <div class="parent">
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <article>I WANT THIS ONE</article>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.grandParent .parent:last-of-type article:last-of-type {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Is this what you wanted? If i understood your question correctly the last article in the last parent should be selected?

Comment: This won't be working. It will not choose the second `I WANT THIS ONE` which has an empty `parent` inside its `grandparents`.

Comment: You are correct about that, i assumed that was a mistake made while pasting the code. Not sure though, hopefully the OP will clarify

Comment: Yep, I tried that but it doesn't select the last article of the first parent if the second parent is empty.

Comment: Understood, I think this is an issue with your html then. CSS expects HTML to conform to a particular structure, if you have random empty divs, it might be better to fix the HTML first.

Comment: @DanielSmith You are correct. I thought it would be too complicated to change the code that renders the second parent div but it wasn't. There was a small bug in the code that was, until now, gone unnoticed. Thanks for your help!